# Error in Notice undefined index in Y-m-d

Tags: indexing, undefined, datediff

When I add account in my system there was an error

*Notice undefined index in Y-m-d*

And here's my code

```
$date1 = new DateTime($rsnew["expirationdate"]);
   $date2 = new DateTime($rsnew["Y-m-d"]);

   $interval = date_diff($date1,$date2));
   $rsnew["noofday"]= $interval->format('%a');

   $date1 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($rsnew["expirationdate"]));
    if($date1 > $date2){
      $rsnew["status"]= '0';
   }else {
      $rsnew["status"]= '1';
   }
   return TRUE;
}
```

I'm using PHPMaker

Thank you for your help

Comment: Where did you define $rsnew before using it?

Comment: I'm using Phpmaker with parameter                                                         function Row_Inserting($rsold, &$rsnew) {